# Update makes system act strange

Tags: unity, updates, compiz

I just downloaded some updates for my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop that has support for Unity 3D. I noticed that one of the updates was for Compiz. I updated it, restarted my system and now everything is different. The font for everything is different (even in Firefox), and none of the stuff that is in `~/Desktop` is displayed on my Desktop. Also pressing the right mouse button on my Desktop does not show a menu.

What's going on? Is this supposed to happen? Is everyone downloading this update having the same problem? How do I fix it? Below are the contents of ~/.xsession-errors:

`Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped`

Below is what the fonts look like now (and I hate how it looks!)

[image: Image with font that I don't like]

Also, I looked at the files in my home directory and found a log that I think was made by OpenJDK. This could have something to do with it because I only noticed it after the system started "acting strange". However, the log is so large, I can't post it *here*. I did, however, put it on my personal Dropbox and shared it. You can see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/taj7mulllh98zap/hs_err_pid2998.log?dl=1). Please help. I have only had Ubuntu on my laptop for three days (but I am not a noob; I have plenty of experience) and I don't want to have to reinstall.

Comment: A screenshot would likely be helpful is this is just a graphical issue....

Comment: I added a screenshot. Remember though, that I am also unable to see any items on my Desktop, use the left mouse button to select stuff on my Desktop, or use the right mouse button to see a menu.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set the fonts and many other things in the configuration. Maybe you just need to play around a bit to find settings you like?
There is plenty of info around for your error message, I suggest some googling. For starters, some people reported `rm ~/.Xauthority` and rebooting helped.

Comment: I accidentally modified a configuration file I wasn't supposed to and my entire system is wrecked! I am going to do a fresh install in the next couple hours. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I removed a package I wasn't supposed to remove and that this problem has nothing to do with Compiz at all. I backed up my documents and music and stuff and did a fresh install. It was successful and all of my programs are back.